# Reading attachments over IMAP in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, imap, attachment

How to read and save mail attachments in db using IMAP?

I used this code to read text contents of email. I need to read attachments with this.

```
  const imap = new Imap({
    user: 'abc@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    tlsOptions: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    authTimeout: 3000
  });


  function openInbox(cb) {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
  }
  //['SUBJECT', 'Give Subject Here']]
  imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var fs = require('fs'), fileStream;
      var f = imap.seq.fetch('714:715', { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)','TEXT'] });
      f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
        // console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
        var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
        msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
          simpleParser(stream, (err, mail) => {
            // console.log(mail.from);            
          });
         
          stream.once('end', function() {
            if (info.which !== 'TEXT')
             {} // console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
            else
              {}// console.log(prefix + 'Body [%s] Finished', inspect(info.which));
          });
        });
        msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
          // console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
        });
        msg.once('end', function() {
          // console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
        });
      });
      f.once('error', function(err) {
        // console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
      });
      f.once('end', function() {
        // console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
        imap.end();
      });
    });
});
  
  imap.once('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  
  imap.once('end', function() {
    // console.log('Connection ended');
  });
  
  imap.connect();
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Now I got attachment file with this code, but I don't know where I declare the file storing path..

Comment: You mean, how to save the file on the server? Take a look at [this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/).

Comment: Yes, to save server or to get file as url